# Program stuck on reverse python guessing game

Tags: python

My program is stuck while it tells you to think of a number in the range of selected numbers and I'm unsure how to fix this.

I'm not entirely sure what I'm doing even but the start of the program works properly.

```
from random import randrange
import time


def guessNumber(min_no, max_no):
   try:
      return randrange(min_no, max_no)
   except ValueError:
       return min_no
   left = 0
   right = len(L)-1
   while left<=right:   
      m = (left+right)//2
      if x == L[m]:
         return m
      elif x < L[m]:
         right = m-1
      else:  #  L[m] < x 
         left = m+1


def userNoInput(msg):
   while 1:
      try:
         return int(input(msg))
      except:
         print("Numbers Only !")
         sys.exit(0)

print("Enter two numbers, low then high.")
min_no = userNoInput("low = ")
max_no = userNoInput("high = ")
print ("Think of a number in the range %d and %d."%(min_no, max_no))
max_no += 1

while True:
   guess = guessNumber(min_no, max_no)
count = 0
L = []
for i in range(low, high+1):
   L.append(i)

while True:
   print("Is your number Less than, Greater than, or Equal to %d ?") % (L[(int(len(L)/2))])
   guess = guessNumber(low, high)
   guess = input("Type 'L', 'G' or 'E': ")
   guess = guess.upper()
   if guess == 'E':
      break
   elif guess == 'L': guess < number
   elif guess == 'G': guess > number

   else:
      print (guess)

print ("Your number is" + guess + "." + "I Found it in" + number + "guesses.")
```

> > desired output:

```
Enter two numbers, low then high.
low = 2
high = 18
Think of a number in the range 2 to 18.
Is your number Less than, Greater than, or Equal to 10?
Type 'L', 'G' or 'E': g
Is your number Less than, Greater than, or Equal to 14?
Type 'L', 'G' or 'E': L
Is your number Less than, Greater than, or Equal to 12?
Type 'L', 'G' or 'E': L
Your number is 11. I found it in 3 guesses.
```

Comment: Your `while True:  guess = guessNumber(min_no, max_no)` does not break at any condition. No wonder it is an infinite loop

Comment: why do you have code after the return statement in _guessNumber_?

Comment: while True is  the one that is causing problems

Comment: what is it i should remove?

Comment: Change the input to lower/upper case. Then check with appropriate value (i.e. 'L'/'l' etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Yep, the infinite loop in over first guessing caused program to hang.
There should be only one event loop, something like this:

```
from random import randrange
import time


def guess_number(min_no, max_no):
   return randrange(min_no, max_no)


def user_num_input(msg):
   try:
      return int(raw_input(msg))
   except ValueError:
      print('Numbers Only!')
      sys.exit(1)


def get_hint(current_guess):
   return raw_input('Is your number Less than, Greater than, or Equal to %d? (L, G, E): ' % current_guess)


print('Enter two numbers, low then high.')
min_no = user_num_input('low = ')
max_no = user_num_input('high = ')
assert max_no >= min_no
print ('Think of a number in the range %d and %d.' % (min_no, max_no))

iteration = 1
while True:
   guess = guess_number(min_no, max_no)
   hint = get_hint(guess)
   while hint not in ['E', 'L', 'G']:
      print('You gave unknown answer. Please retry.')
      hint = get_hint(guess)

   if hint == 'E':
      break
   elif hint == 'L': 
      max_no = guess
   elif hint == 'G': 
      min_no = guess
   else:
      raise ValueError('Unreachable!')

   iteration += 1

print ('Your number is %d. I found it in %d guesses.' % (guess, iteration))
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will do it for you . There were many mistakes in that code of yours :-

1.) Infinite While loop ( while True:
   guess = guessNumber(min_no, max_no) ) .

2.) You dont need lists/arrays for this problem.

3.) while True:
   guess = guessNumber(min_no, max_no) , this function is wrong . since you are returning the value ,it is not going past the except statement.

4.) No need of def userNoInput(msg): function , anyways no issues.

5.) The last line ( Print statement is wrong too )

Hoping this will help you

P.S:- Just a suggestion , whenever you get an infinite loop or some issues like that , you should firstly try yourself by printing statements inside loop and see where the issue is .

```
from random import randrange
import time


def guessNumber(min_no, max_no):
   left = min_no
   right = max_no
   if left == right:
      return left
   m = (left+right)/2
   return m

def userNoInput(msg):
   while 1:
      try:
          return int(input(msg))
      except:
          print("Numbers Only !")
          sys.exit(0)

print("Enter two numbers, low then high.")
min_no = userNoInput("low = ")
max_no = userNoInput("high = ")
# print min_no,max_no
print ("Think of a number in the range %d and %d."%(min_no, max_no))
max_no += 1

count = 0

while True:
   count+=1
   guess = guessNumber(min_no, max_no)
   print("Is your number Less than, Greater than, or Equal to %d ?") %guess
   temp = raw_input("Type 'L', 'G' or 'E': ")
   temp = temp.upper()
   if temp == 'E':   
       break
   elif temp == 'L':
       max_no = guess-1;

   elif temp == 'G':
       min_no = guess+1;

print "Your number is %r . I Found it in %r guesses." %(guess,count)
```